# Bookmarking a question

Tags: discussion

Often, it happens that you encounter a puzzle, which you want to solve later or want to see the solution when it is posted. Often, there is multiple such question and it is not possible to keep track of all of them in your mind. In this scenario, it might be helpful to have some sort of "bookmarking" process.

However, the only way I could find to achieve this was by favouriting the question. However, the favourite button should be for ... well, favourite questions. Is there any other way to do this, or at least some kind of workaround?

Answer (score 1):

You could bookmark it in your browser in a "view later" folder.

Alternately, you can sort your favorite questions by most recently favorited, and it should serve the same purpose.

Comment: Managing bookmarks in a browser can be painful and doesn't work when I use the site from different devices. The second choice is also the closest I could find.

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't a better option from within Stack Exchange. I might suggest using a bookmark synchronization service, though; i.e. Chrome has built-in bookmark sync.